# Basic Tooltip (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip

HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip">Open Tooltip</a>
<div id="tooltip">Tooltip Content</div>
```

I checked out some tooltip plugins but my requirement is a really basic tooltip that shows a hidden div on hover. All plugins either have too many advanced options that I don't require and have already styled tooltips that might be difficult to modify.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to show a hiddev div in a tooltip. how then user will came to know so that he hover mouse over there.

Comment: +1 for stripping the requirement down to a minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can roll your own.

My suggestion is just to store the `clientX` and `clientY` properties of the mouse event object that is passed to the `onmouseover` event handler. Then set the CSS onscreen position ( `left`, `top` ) of the hidden div to those coordinates and you're golden. **Make sure that the div's `position` CSS property is `absolute`**

A quick untested example just to give you an idea:

```
$( '[rel="tooltip"]' ).hover( function(e) {
   var x = e.clientX;
   var y = e.clientY;
   _div.css( { top: y, left: x, position: 'absolute' } )
       .fadeIn();
}, function() {
    _div.fadeOut();
} );
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Just the positioning is incorrect; it opens at the bottom-right instead I want it at top-right. I guess I have to find the height of #tooltip and set it as top:-[height], no?

Comment: Try `clientX` and `clientY` instead of `pageX` and `pageY`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code for a really simple CSS tooltip that I use:

CSS:

```
  .name a:hover {
background:#ffffff; 
text-decoration:none;
}

.name a.tooltip span {
display:none; 
padding:5px; 
margin-left:108px; 
width:100px;
}

.name a.tooltip:hover span {
display:inline; 
position:absolute; 
background:#ffffff; 
border:1px solid #cccccc; 
color:#000000;
top:5px;
left:-15px;
}
```

The top and left properties make it float above the text. Change this to position it where you like. Also, change `display:inline;` to `display:block;` if you want it to behave like a normal div for positioning.

HTML:

```
     <div class="name">
       Name 
        <a class="tooltip" href="#">
          Tooltip
             <span>
               Tooltip text here.
             </span>
        </a>.
     </div>
```

Comment: Surprisingly simple. Though I came here looking for a jQuery solution, I'm happy to opt for this pure CSS approach. The only downside is the absence of the fade in/out that's typical to the conventional tooltip and so easily achievable with jQuery. That being said, it appears to be possible with pure CSS: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/opacity/fadein.html

Comment: It's possible to get the fade with CSS3 transitions. But this won't be supported in legacy browsers.

Comment: Good point, CSS3 makes more sense than the older workaround I linked to. IE appears to be the only browser that doesn't support the CSS3 transition property. I've used CSS3 PIE (http://css3pie.com/) in the past to great success for achieving CSS3 border radius on IE6+. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to support transitions (http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/). Existing discussion on IE transition support here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103283/does-internet-explorer-support-css-transitions

Answer (score 2):

Here's an even more basic tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/54/

hides the tooltip:

```
.tooltip span {
display:none; 
}
```

Shows the tooltip:

```
.tooltip:hover span {
display:inline; 
}
```

Comment: Note that this just hides and unhides some inline text. Usually, when people say "tooltip" they mean something that at the very least hovers, and is either in relation to the mouse or to the thing that the tooltip is applied to.

Answer (score 1):

if you just wanna show the div on the mouse hover use:

```
$('a[rel="tooltip"]').hover(
   function(){ $('#tooltip').show() }, //or maybe use fadeIn() instead of .show() 
   function(){ $('#tooltip').hide() }
)
```

you can integrate markcial's solution in the functions to make the tooltip div appear next to your cursor.

would look like this

```
$('a[rel="tooltip"]').hover(
   function(e){ $('#tooltip').css({ position:'absolute', top:e.pageY, left:e.pageX }).show() }, //or maybe use fadeIn() instead of .show() 
   function(){ $('#tooltip').hide() }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[rel=tooltip]').bind('mouseover',function(e){
  e=e?e:window.event;
  $('#tooltip').css({
    position:'absolute',
    top:e.pageY,
   left:e.pageX
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same but without javascript or jquery. I found following way using pure CSS3 transitions.

**CSS3**

```
a.tooltip span
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
}
a:hover.tooltip span
{
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-opacity: 0.90;
  -moz-opacity: 0.90;
  opacity: 0.90;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="tooltip" href="#">Hover Me
    <span>Some text information that you want to display in tooltip</span></a>
```

For more details with live demo, visit [Tooltip Example using CSS3 Transitions](http://www.webblogsforyou.com/tooltip-example-show-hide-hint-help-text-using-css3-transition/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Plug-ins are usually extensive. It's better to write something yourself. Add an attribute to any element on the page: tooltip = "content". You can change the appearance as you like, I only added what is necessary to CSS.

```js
//tooltip v. 1.0 by Krzysztof Antosik
//show tooltip 
function tooltipShow(){ 
if(typeof($("#tooltip")) != "undefined" && $("#tooltip") !== null){
  $("#tooltip").remove();
 }
 var title = $(this).attr("tooltip");
 $("body").append("<span id=\"tooltip\">" + title + "</span>")
}

//hide tooltip    
function tooltipHide() {
 $("#tooltip").remove();
}
//run tooplip
$("[tooltip]").hover(tooltipShow, tooltipHide);
//move tooltip
$("[tooltip]").on('mousemove', function(e){
 var positionY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
 var positionX = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
 var endX = $(document).width() - 70;
 var margin = 30;
  //on top
  if ((positionX > 50) && (positionX < endX)){
   if(positionY <= (40)){
    var fixX = - $("#tooltip").width()/2;
    var fixY = margin;
   }else {
    var fixX = - $("#tooltip").width()/2;
    var fixY = - margin;
   }
  //on feft
  }else if(positionX <= 50){
   var fixX = margin;
   var fixY = - $("#tooltip").height()/2;
  //on right
  }else if(positionX >= endX){
   var fixX = - (margin * 2/3) - $("#tooltip").width() ;
   var fixY = - $("#tooltip").height()/2; 
  }
 $('#tooltip').css({
  left:  e.pageX + fixX, 
  top:   e.pageY + fixY
 });
});
```

```css
#tooltip{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-align: right;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/css/tooltip.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sample" tooltip="1" style="position:fixed; left:300px; top:40px; background-color:red; height:30px;width:30px;">aaa</div>
<div class="sample" tooltip="2" style="position:fixed; left:30px; top:40px; background-color:red; height:30px;width:30px;">aaa</div>
<div class="sample" tooltip="3" style="position:fixed; left:30px; top:300px; background-color:red; height:30px;width:30px;">aaa</div>
<div class="sample" tooltip="4" style="position:fixed; left:30px; bottom:40px; background-color:red; height:30px;width:30px;">aaa</div>
<div class="sample" tooltip="5" style="position:fixed; left:300px; bottom:40px; background-color:red; height:30px;width:30px;">aaa</div>
<div class="sample" tooltip="6" style="position:fixed; right:3px; bottom:100px; background-color:red; height:30px;width:30px;">aaa</div>
</body>
<script src="tooltip.js"></script>
</html>
```