# Does Internet Explorer support CSS transitions?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions

[CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) are a very neat way of animating changes in CSS properties. Do any versions of Internet Explorer support them?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The page you link to has a [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility).

```
Chrome
    1.0 (-webkit prefix)

Firefox
    4.0 (2.0) (-moz prefix)
    16.0 (16.0) (no prefix)

Internet Explorer
    10.0 (no prefix)

Opera
    10.5 (-o prefix)  
    12.0 (no prefix)

Safari
    3.2 (-webkit prefix)
```

There is also an article on [MSDN about CSS3 transitions in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: of course, pp7 is no longer the most recent release of IE9. But it's recent enough that it's got all the major features that IE9 is going to have when it's launched. MS are being strict about only implementing features with a finalised spec; CSS transitions is not finalised yet so IE9 won't have it (and also hence why all the browsers that do imlpement it are using a vendor prefix on the property).

Comment: Okay, I won't lie — I was aware of the answer, but I was surprised that I could not find the answer here on Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: CSS transitions are being promised for IE10 (although the current preview version doesn't support them). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/12/native-html5-first-ie10-platform-preview-available-for-download.aspx

Comment: that findMeByIP site seems great but outdated (firefox 4 is the latest version they have). Also IE is so bad and has been such a pain to work with that makes me want to create a virus that would silently replace ie by chrome..

Comment: I've noticed `transition` works for me on localhost with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` but not when I remove this and put it on the server...  Strange. (Looking into it some more)

Comment: @NickBedford: My experience is that IE9 has no major issues with standards compliance. The issues are basically fancy effects that are not very important for the overall design of a web site. This means that the issues still remaining is in the category *"The site works - no worries. Missing design feature is so minor that it is not worth the effort to provide workaround for IE."*

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using http://caniuse.com/ to check the support and compatibility of html/css features, as it will display data of most browsers on the market share.

Here's the link for transitions: http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions

For older versions of IE, there are various polyfills which you can find on the rich www

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support to CSS transforms and transitions in IE8.

Perhaps you need to go with some available JavaScript libraries to produce such effects:

- www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/#more-896
- www.jqueryui.com/effect/

A trade-off : CSS transitions take advantage of native graphic acceleration of browser (GPU) and thus are smoother than using JavaScript effects.

Comment: useragentman's blog is mostly about transforms, not about transitions ... as an alternative, I might mention jquery's animate()