# CSS transition and animation not working in IE (works in Firefox/Chrome)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

How can I edit my code to make it work in IE. It works great in Firefox and Chrome.
I can't figure out the correct attributes for calling the `transition` and `animation` in Internet Explorer.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample for Konstantin</title>
<style type="text/css">

.text p
{text-align:center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
left:50%;

}
.text {

    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 110px;
    }

.text h1 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'footlight mt light';
    font-size: 50px;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .9s;
    letter-spacing: -10px;

    }
    a { text-decoration:none }

    .text h1 span a {
        -webkit-transition: 0.9s ;
                color: #9C948D;
        }

        .text h1:hover span a {
            color: blue;
            }


</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>

    <div class="text"><p><h1>This is a sample, <br />
   My Name is Matthew<br />Here is <span><a href="http://www.nba.com" >NBA Website</a>.</span><br />This is very simple<br />Here is  <span><a href="http://www.facebook.com" > Facebook!</a>.</span></h1>
</p></div>
</body></html>
```

EDIT: is there anyway to use like a div block or anything to make a similar effect in ie?

Comment: I don't think IE 9 supports transitions does it? EDIT: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103283/does-internet-explorer-support-css-transitions)

Comment: http://www.laughingsamurai.com/
i want it to look something like this, and this works in IE

Comment: `-moz-` for Firefox, `-o-` for Opera, `-ms-` for IE. But IE does not support transitions or animations yet (see answer by Rich Bradshaw).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE10 is the first IE to support transitions. I usually either ignore the animation in old browsers (old IE often -> old computer, so animations are often choppy).

If it's really required then use jQuery to patch it up. Downside is that animating color isn't built into jQuery so you'll need a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the "-webkit" part of your CSS property. It will only work in webkit browsers (Chrome+Safari) IE does not support "-webkit" CSS properties