# something similar to transition for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, cross-browser, css-transitions

i know that IE10 supports transition but is there something similar i can do to make it for on older version of IE, all i want is for a box to slowly move up when its hovered over, i have it working on all other web browsers. thanks code below

```
    .boxslider:hover{
    margin:37px 0 0 0;
    transition: margin 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.7s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.7s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: margin 0.7s; /* Opera */
    }
```

Comment: [Already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103283/does-internet-explorer-support-css-transitions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Modernizr.js in order to know if CSS Transitions are supported by the current browser: http://modernizr.com/

If they are not supported load a JavaScript file with some jQuery fallbacks (Events handlers with animation functions as callbacks).

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.csstransitions,
  nope: 'IE-transitions-fallback.js'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out, it is something like an html5shiv, but for css3.

http://code.google.com/p/css3shiv/

This also shows microsoft-only css that gets the job done. My recommendation is that if you use this method, you should make a ms only stylesheet and load that with a conditional ie statement because as [the article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/) states, the ms-only css won't validate because it isn't css.

[This is another article with some more tips.](http://www.amicontech.com/blog/css3-compatibility-with-all-browsers-including-ie/)