# CSS Transitions for Firefox, Opera, and IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, opera, css-transitions

I'm trying to get my hover transitions to work in opera and firefox.  It works fine in Chrome, but I have not verified it in IE or Safari. Do I need to change or add?

```
#redbox a {
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.15s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: initial;
}

#redbox a:hover {background:#6C6C6C;}
```

Comment: See also [Does Internet Explorer support CSS transitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103283/does-internet-explorer-support-css-transitions)

Comment: For Opera see http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.12/css/transitions/#anima

Answer (score 1):

You've only included the prefixes for webkit in your css, so consequently it works fine in Chrome, and most likely Safari as well, but not anywhere else. You'll need to include the mozilla vendor prefix to get it working in firefox:

```
#redbox a {
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.15s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: initial;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.15s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-transition-delay: initial;
}
```

Same goes for opera which uses `-o-` as its prefix. As for IE, not sure if it supports css transitions, you'll need to check that at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility) or [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), etc.

**Update**: As noted by @BoltClock and @Boris Zbarsky below, it's often a good idea to include the non-prefixed, standards versions of these sorts of vendor-specific rules as well, depending on what browsers/versions you want to target.

Comment: IE10 supports transitions unprefixed. The `-ms-` prefix is not used in any stable version, but it was used by the IE10 PPs.

Comment: Firefox 16 and newer also supports these properties without prefixes.

Comment: @Erik does your version of FF support transitions? Works for me in FF 16 and 17: http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/2kfCY/

Comment: Opera 12.10 have unprefixed these properties since version 12.10