# Flexislider is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use flexislider in my webpage. But what is the problem is, the slider works fine in chrome, firefox and IE10. But the problem arises when coming to IE9 and earlier versions.Please anyone help me to fix this problem.

I think following Script is having the problem:

```
if (slider.transitions) {
    target = (vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + target + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + target + ",0,0)";
    dur = (dur !== undefined) ? (dur/1000) + "s" : "0s";
    slider.container.css("-" + slider.pfx + "-transition-duration", dur);
    slider.container.css("transition-duration", dur);   
    slider.container.css("-" + slider.pfx + "-transition-duration", dur);alert(slider.pfx);
}
```

But if I remove the `slider.pfx` also the problem remains same. The code executes properly but slider won't move. If any one able find out the problem. Please answer for this question.

Comment: IE9 doesn't support css3 transition

Comment: Just need to implement a fallback, and use jquery for IE9

Answer (score 0):

It not works in **[<=IE 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration)**

```
Chrome
    1.0 (-webkit prefix)

Firefox
    4.0 (2.0) (-moz prefix)
    16.0 (16.0) (no prefix)

Internet Explorer
    10.0 (no prefix)

Opera
    10.5 (-o prefix)  
    12.0 (no prefix)

Safari
    3.2 (-webkit prefix)
```

And try to use `json` in `css()` like,

```
if (slider.transitions) {
    target = (vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + target + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + target + ",0,0)";
    dur = (dur !== undefined) ? (dur/1000) + "s" : "0s";
    slider.container.css({"-" + slider.pfx + "-transition-duration", dur,"transition-duration", dur});  
    // pass json object at once only 
    alert(slider.pfx);
}
```

Read this [Does Internet Explorer support CSS transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103283/does-internet-explorer-support-css-transitions)

Comment: I didn't got what you mean to pass json object.

Comment: You have called `slider.container.css() three times` so you can `call it once` with a `single object of key-value pairs`. Read http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Comment: I passed the values as you said. But now also slider was not working. Is any plugins available to debug in IE like firebug..