# Browser CSS transform vertical from cube flip

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need some help with a 3d tranform. The transform is on the a:hover event and uses a:hover and a:before pseudo element to be transformed into a vertical flip, it's like a crad filp but it starts the flip at the base line of the menu, it should look like a cube flipping upwards. Here is the code on code [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FDmdB) Please try and get this to work in Webkit and Mozilla and of course IE, please see what you can do.

the example i have is limited but it does work in FireFox and no other browsers so this would be better tested in IE and chrome first.[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FnqCp)

PS. The pink a:before elements need to be transformed on a flat perpective surface at the bottom of the A tag and the a:before tag should animate upwards in place of the hovered anchor tag (-90deg I think), when it animate the pink tag shown in place of the first tag

Answer (score 0):

You should post code rather than links. However, from your codepen I can tell you're not using vendor prefixes to support multiple browsers.

When you use `transition`, `transform`, etc you should write

```
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
-mos-transition: all .3s;
-ms-transition: all .3s;
-o-transition: all .3s;
transition: all .3s;
```

See this SO question: [Does Internet Explorer support CSS transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103283/does-internet-explorer-support-css-transitions/5103296#5103296)

Comment: IE Supports IE trans-tions and trasnforms

Comment: can you help me to get this code working properly please